# A problem with image capture on Motorola Milestone

Tags: android, camera, snapshot, milestone

Below is the simple code fragment to illustrate the problem.
Why the value of the field "tag" logged in method "onActivityResult" not being "tag_modified"?
I also tried others async call of "startActivityForResult", but no such problem exists.
The problem merely occurs on my Moto Milestone, but everything goes well on HTC G7.

```
public class HelloSnapshot extends Activity {

        private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HelloSnapshot.class.getName());

        final int REQUESTCODE_SNAPSHOT = 1;

        String tag = "tag_initial";

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                Button button = new Button(this);
                button.setText("BUTTON");
                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                                tag = "tag_modified";

                                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUESTCODE_SNAPSHOT);
                        }
                });

                setContentView(button, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }

        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode , Intent data) {
                switch (requestCode) {
                case REQUESTCODE_SNAPSHOT:
                        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                                logger.info(tag);

                        }
                        break;
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I`ve found it out...

Some android OS kill the snapshot calling Activity to avoid memory related exception.
So, I have to save all the states via method onSaveInstanceState, and retrieve them when the calling activity was constructed again.

Further more, I also found out that, all the information stored in the memory is prone to be erased, like those Singleton objects. Thus I have to do saving by some persistent storage approaches, and restore them later.